# Powershell could not find part of the path

Tags: powershell, path

Been at this for a few hours. I'm trying to grab the software list from a windows machine, and export that list as a CSV using the location as $env:userprofile and the path to the file "Software Inventories\$Username.csv"

I get the following error

```
Export-Csv : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\mylogin\Software Inventories\@{UserName=domain\mylogin}.csv'.
At C:\Users\mylogin\Dropbox\Powershell\GetSoftwareList.ps1:24 char:191
+ ... e, Vendor, Version | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-Csv -Path $Path
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

And the code is as follows:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host 'Enter IP or computer name'
$WindowsVersion = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential 'domain\myadmin' -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ForEach-Object -MemberName Caption


If ($WindowsVersion -match 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise'){

    $Username = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
    $Path = Join-Path $env:userprofile "Software Inventories\$Username.csv"
    Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential "domain\myadmin" -ClassName Win32_InstalledWin32Program | Select Name, Vendor, Version | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv -Path $Path
    Write-Host "Windows version is $WindowsVersion"

}Elseif ($WindowsVersion -match 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise') {

    $Username = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
    $Path = Join-Path $env:userprofile "Software Inventories\$Username.csv"
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential 'domain\myadmin' -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms | Select DisplayName, Vendor, Version | Sort-Object DisplayName | Export-Csv -Path $Path
    Write-Host "Windows version is $WindowsVersion"
```

Am I not using Join-Path correctly?

On a side note, how can I grab just the username as a string from $Username and omit the rest?

Comment: To split the username use this line 
$Username = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName).UserName.Split("\")[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Username = (Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName).Split('\')[1]
$Username = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName).Split('\')[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. So as I understand. The \ delimiter omits everything before it and only saves what comes after it

Comment: What function does the "[1]" have in that line?

Comment: The UserName property will return a string in the format "[Domain]\\[UserName]". With the split `.Split('\')` we can do exactly what it says and split the string in two parts using the '\' (backslash) as separator. The output is a zero indexed array of two strings. The first element is the domain with a 0 index in the array `"domain\user".Split('\')[0]`, the second is the username which has the next index number in the array, which is 1 `"domain\user".Split('\')[1]`

Answer (score 2):

The variable $UserName is a hashtable with a property named UserName and a value of domain\mylogin. To select only the value of the property, use the ExpandProperty parameter from Select-Object.

```
$Username = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation of the $Username variable :)